# How can I replace the first element of an HTML string with an h1?

Tags: javascript, html

I have some HTML:

```
<p>Let's see if this works</p>
<p>Let's use some really complicated words like "neural-style-transfer" to help lower that a bit.</p>
<ul>
  <li>Having some basic stats is pretty cool! How can I colorize some of the text?</li>
  <li>Do I really want to do this??</li>
  <li>I want to throttle. I want to see if this will work.</li>
</ul>
```

I want to replace the first `<p>` with `<h1>`. However, the first tag may be any tag, not necessarily a `p`. How can I accomplish this with JavaScript?

Comment: Let's starts with the customary, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var givenhtmlasstring = "<p>Let's see if this works</p><p>Let's use some really complicated words like 'neural-style-transfer' to help lower that a bit.</p><ul><li>Having some basic stats is pretty cool! How can I colorize some of the text?</li><li>Do I really want to do this??</li><li>I want to throttle. I want to see if this will work.</li></ul>";

var givenhtml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(givenhtmlasstring, "text/xml");
var selectedfirsttag = givenhtml.firstChild.localName; // this will return "p"
var htmlofselectedtag = givenhtml.firstChild.innerHTML; // this will return html of "p"

var givenElement = givenhtml.querySelector(selectedfirsttag);
var newElement = document.createElement('h1');
newElement.innerHTML = htmlofselectedtag;
givenElement.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, givenElement);
```

now your givenhtml will have replaced code. Please try this once.

Comment: I may not have a DOM. I just have the HTML

Comment: `var givenhtml = new DOMParser().parseFromString(givenhtmlasstring, "text/xml");` using this statement, I am just to assign the given html to the variable.if you have HTML, is it possible for you to assign to givenhtml?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
let parags = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
let p = parags[0];
if(p){
      var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
      h1.innerHTML = p.innerHTML;
      p.parentNode.replaceChild(h1, p);
}
```

```html
<p>Let's see if this works</p><p>Let's use some really complicated words like "neural-style-transfer" to help lower that a bit.</p><ul><li>Having some basic stats is pretty cool! How can I colorize some of the text?</li><li>Do I really want to do this??</li><li>I want to throttle. I want to see if this will work.</li></ul>
```

If you don't have access to the `DOM` and just want to replace the text, you can do a simple `replace` for the first occurrence of the tags:

```js
let str = `<p>Let's see if this works</p><p>Let's use some really complicated words like "neural-style-transfer" to help lower that a bit.</p><ul><li>Having some basic stats is pretty cool! How can I colorize some of the text?</li><li>Do I really want to do this??</li><li>I want to throttle. I want to see if this will work.</li></ul>`;
str = str.replace("<p>", "<h1>");
str = str.replace("</p>", "</h1>");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: I want to replace it in a string. I may not have a DOM

Comment: Can you give more details? Aren't you working on a web page?

Comment: No, it's basically pure text

Comment: @Shamoon I added the case for simple text to the answer

Comment: Close, but remember, that first tag can be anything, not necessarily `<p>`

Comment: Yes this searches for the first ``<p>`` and ``</p>`` and replaces them

Comment: Right, but I want to replace the first element, regardless of which tag it is.